# Pandas: Reorder a data frame based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, function

I would like to reorder my dataframe based on certain conditions

My original dataframe looks like

```
Merchant name         original_rnk
Boohoo                1
PRETTYLITTLETHING     2
ASOS US               3
PRINCESS POLLY        4
URBAN OUTFITTERS      5
KIM+ONO               6
```

And there is a reference dataframe that has some merchant information

```
Merchant name         order_cnt     profit     epc      
Boohoo                200           30         0.6
PRETTYLITTLETHING     100           -60        -0.4
ASOS US               50            100        1.0
PRINCESS POLLY        80            50         0.8
URBAN OUTFITTERS      120           -20        -0.1
KIM+ONO               500           90         0.7
```

I would like to give a new rank to these merchant based on their epc if their order_cnt >= 100 and profit >=0. **The first merchant will always be the first no matter how much its order_cnt and profit are**, but for the rest whose order_cnt <100 or profit <0, r their original order.

So my desired output is

```
Merchant name         new_rnk     original_rnk
Boohoo                1           1
PRETTYLITTLETHING     3           2
ASOS US               4           3
PRINCESS POLLY        5           4
URBAN OUTFITTERS      6           5
KIM+ONO               2           6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data provided in the question:

```py
info = pd.DataFrame({
    'Merchant name': ['Boohoo', 'PRETTYLITTLETHING', 'ASOS US', 'PRINCESS POLLY', 'URBAN OUTFITTERS', 'KIM+ONO'],
    'order_cnt': [200, 100, 50, 80, 120, 500],
    'profit': [30, -60, 100, 50, -20, 90],
    'epc': [0.6, -0.4, 1.0, 0.8, -0.1, 0.7]
})
```

Split the data into the first row (head), the rows that satisfy the condition (mask) and the rows that don't (pos and neg):

```py
head = info.head(1)
tail = info.iloc[1:]
mask = tail.eval('order_cnt >= 100 and profit >= 0')
pos = tail[mask]
neg = tail[~mask]
```

Sort the positive rows using the desired criteria (epc) and concatenate the three partitions back together:

```py
df = pd.concat([head, pos.sort_values('epc', ascending=False), neg])
```

To get output as presented in the original question (with both the original and the new ranks and sorted by the original rank) add these lines:

```py
df['new_rank'] = range(1, 7)
df['original_rank'] = df['Merchant name'].map(ranks.set_index('Merchant name')['original_rnk'])
df.sort_values('original_rank')[['Merchant name', 'new_rank', 'original_rank']]
```

where `ranks` is the "original data frame":

```py
ranks = pd.DataFrame({
    'Merchant name': ['Boohoo', 'PRETTYLITTLETHING', 'ASOS US', 'PRINCESS POLLY', 'URBAN OUTFITTERS', 'KIM+ONO'],
    'original_rnk': range(1, 7)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code for the desired output;

```
import pandas as pd

original_rank_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Merchant name': ['Boohoo', 'PRETTYLITTLETHING', 'ASOS US', 'PRINCESS POLLY', 'URBAN OUTFITTERS', 'KIM+ONO'],
                                    'original_rnk': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]})

reference_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Merchant name': ['Boohoo', 'PRETTYLITTLETHING', 'ASOS US', 'PRINCESS POLLY', 'URBAN OUTFITTERS', 'KIM+ONO'],
                                'order_cnt': [200, 100, 50, 80, 120, 500],
                                'profit': [30, -60, 100, 50, -20, 90],
                                'epc': [0.6, -0.4, 1.0, 0.8, -0.1, 0.7]})

final_table = pd.concat([reference_frame[((reference_frame['order_cnt'] >= 100) & (reference_frame['epc'] >= 0))], 
                         reference_frame[~((reference_frame['order_cnt'] >= 100) & (reference_frame['epc'] >= 0))]], axis=0)
final_table = final_table.reset_index().rename({'index':'original_rnk'}, axis = 'columns').reset_index().rename({'index':'new_rnk'}, axis = 'columns')[['Merchant name', 'new_rnk', 'original_rnk']]
final_table[['new_rnk', 'original_rnk']] += 1
final_table.sort_values('original_rnk')
```

> Output

```
       Merchant name  new_rnk  original_rnk
0             Boohoo        1             1
2  PRETTYLITTLETHING        3             2
3            ASOS US        4             3
4     PRINCESS POLLY        5             4
5   URBAN OUTFITTERS        6             5
1            KIM+ONO        2             6
```

> Explanation

The first step is to filter the dataframe by desired qualities *reference_frame[((reference_frame['order_cnt'] >= 100) & (reference_frame['epc'] >= 0))*. Since these are mutually exclusive sets, we can use the negation (~) to get the rest.Then, we concat these two dataframes and extract the original index. We assign a new index by resetting. In the last step, we increment the index values since they start with 0 but the desired output from 1.